# xcode 9.2 IBAction and IBOutlet indicators not getting filled in

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9

Has anyone seen this problem and found a solution? My iOS app has intermittent crashes because I think the project is messed up somehow. I have a screenshot of my custom view controller class which is selected in the storyboard. If I connect all the actions and outlets, the indicators will get filled in, but when I restart xcode, they're empty again. The interesting thing is that they're not disconnected, because the app will run fine. It's only sometimes that I get an unhandled exception which complains that one of my outlet classes are not key value coded. When I restart xcode, the problem "sometimes" goes away.

There is one clue to this: I didn't see this problem until I added a custom view which uses a xib file. But what's interesting is that the custom view isn't even used in this view controller, and all of my view controllers have the same problem.

You can see here in the screenshots that all the outlet indicators are empty (yet the app works), and you can see that both action methods indicators aren't filled in either, yet they both work.

Edit: posted better screenshots with more examples.

[image: IBOutlets show no connections but work]

[image: IBActions show no connections but work]

Comment: Paste code not images.

Comment: The functions are not even declared as `@IBAction`, therefore you should not be able to connect them. However, if the connection already exists in xib, removing `@IBAction` won't break it. The indicators are not really safe. It's impossible for Xcode to always detect the connection.

Comment: try clean and build as well.

Comment: I've done the whole clean, build, reconnect, etc.

Comment: wait until indexing finishes , always this happen when you copy paste controllers from another storyboards

Comment: try to right click on  'custom view''s xib file, are there all Outlet connection's right ? Maybe you coped that view, because when you copy view outlets are duplicated

Comment: @u84six make sure there is only one connection for every outlet in storyboard or xib.

Comment: @Sulthan I didn't remove anything. I created the methods the usual way by dragging from the storyboard to code, yet the connection doesn't happen (but the functions work).

Comment: @u84six Check the connection in the storyboard, not in source code.

Comment: The connections all look fine in the storyboard. No dupes, nothing. Just the single connections to each outlet and action. Keep in mind that I have 5 view controllers and 1 custom view that are all experiencing the same problem. Even the ones I haven't touched in a while.

Comment: @u84six Is it possible you are trying to load them from a different bundle or something? That could happen if your code is in a library. Also make sure the class names and module names are correct in storyboards.

Comment: @Sulthan no library, nothing. Basic single-page app, 5 screens, 1 custom view. That's pretty much it.

Comment: @u84six Last idea - look into your filesystem and check there are no files not included in project. One typical error is when there is another resource with the same name but different data or a swift file with the same class but not part of the project. The compiler can pick them up by mistake instead of the file you want.

Comment: @TusharSharma in this case, pasting code won't help since the problem is about the IB connection indicators.

Comment: @Sulthan that was a good suggestion, but I see no dupe files. I really think this has to do with adding the xib file to my project. It all seemed to happen at that point. But the xib looks fine, the custom view works fine, so kind of stuck on this one.

Comment: Opening and closing the storyboard that contains those outlets would usually do the trick iff you really connected the outlets. Strange but this happens to me lot of times.

Comment: @BadhanGanesh do you mean, removing it from the project then reloading it?

Comment: No just opening the storyboard and visiting that particular view controller and then coming back to check if the outlets seem connected. Btw is the app working with those outlets? Are you able to modify the outlet when running app?

Comment: @BadhanGanesh Yes, I've tried clicking on everything. And all the ibactions and everything are working. The only problems here are the indicators themselves looking disconnected and the occasional unexplainable crash.

Comment: I've submitted a defect to Apple Bug Reporter and it's currently getting processed (I've also uploaded my project for them to see the problem).

Comment: I am getting the same issue with Xcode 10 beta 3. I just started the project yesterday, did all the control-drag connections and they were there. Now the bullets are empty.

Comment: @MicheleDall'Agata I haven't found a work-around yet, but I know that the defect has been acknowledged by the developers. But xcode has so many bugs, I'm not sure how long it will take them to fix it since it only happens in rare situations. The strange thing is that I completely uninstalled and reinstalled, and I still have the problem (even with the new versions that have come out since then).

Comment: @u84six I have opened a Bug Report as well, attaching my project. It doesn't seem to cause any run-time issue, though. The only workaround I have found is to drag the outlets again.

Answer (score 0):

This Question is almost a year old but I'm going to answer anyway:

What I did was to delete the View that I had the problems with and remade it, by

1. drag a View Controller to the Storyboard from the Object Library.
2. create a new Swift file by clicking File > New > File and then Cocoa Touch Class. I gave it a name and made sure it has the subclass "UIViewController" and then click "Create".
3. Back to the storyboard, I selected the newly created UIViewController (not the view and neither the scene) and pulled up the identity inspector on the right-most panel of xcode and entered my new UIViewController class in the class-field in the Custom Class section.

And then I just redid all the seques with the ctrl-click-hold-and-drag-spiel and it worked as it was supposed to.

Hope this helps anyone.